# wordpressで固定ページ内でpostするとsessionがクリアされる

Tags: wordpress, session

環境：
docker（image: wordpress:php8.1）

wordpress内で固定ページを作り、同じURL内でGETとPOSTそれぞれで処理を分岐させています。
sessionの制御はfunction.php内に記述し、指定の固定ページ以外を表示した時にセッションクリアするようにしています。

固定ページのURL：
[www.example.com/hogehoge/](http://www.example.com/hogehoge/)

themes/test/function.php:

```
<?php
function contents_session_start(){
  if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
    session_start();
  }
}
add_action('init', 'contents_session_start');

function contents_session_destroy(){
  // 特定の固定ページ以外ではセッションを削除
  if (!is_page('hogehoge')) {
    unset($_SESSION);
    session_destroy();
  }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'contents_session_destroy');
?>
```

themes/test/header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/favicon.gif" />
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

themes/test/page-hogehoge.php:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['hogehoge'])) {
  $_SESSION['hogehoge'] = [
    'count' => 0
  ];
}

$_SESSION['hogehoge']['count']++;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  if (isset($_POST['move'])) {
      die;
  }
}
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php
var_dump($_SESSION['hogehoge']);
?>
<form method="POST" action="./" target="_blank">
  <button type="submit" name="move">ボタン</button>
</form>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

formのメソッドを"GET"にするとセッションは消えませんでした。
POST送信時はそもそもセッションはクリアされるのでしょうか？

また、なぜかheader.php内のタグを削除すると function.php で session_start() が実行されず、
if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) の条件が常に正になってしまいますが、
こちらの理由もわかるようでしたら教えて頂きたいです。

【補足】

formのactionを別の固定ページ（/aaa）に設定し、function.phpでのセッションクリアの条件を

```
!is_page('consultant') && !is_page('aaa')
```

とした場合はセッションが消えることなく続きました。
同一URL内でPOSTすることが条件のようです。